# docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind:

Tags: docker, iis

I'm trying to run a docker image on my windows 10 pro workstation, and I'm getting this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I'm running this command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
```

And getting this response back:

```
Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from docker/getting-started
188c0c94c7c5: Pull complete
617561f33ec6: Pull complete
7d856acdaa9c: Pull complete
a0d3c6e28e6d: Pull complete
af69a9b963c8: Pull complete
0739f3815ad8: Pull complete
7c7b75d0baf8: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:b821569034e3b5fae03b40e64a866017067f3bf17effe185b782bdbf02179528
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker/getting-started:latest
7907f6de2b55cc2d66b5ed3a642ac1a97e5bb5ecda5fcf76ff60d7236e8fd32d
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

How can I run a Docker container and get past this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check if somthing is listening on port `80` by running `PowerShell` command:

`Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess`

If the response is something like this:

```
 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
0     0.20       4.87       0.00       4   0 System
```

Then the it is taken.
terminate the process or simply change the port

```
docker run -d -p 81:81 docker/getting-started 5a0b1202f48ef63c06d75c2f26be2a05f29aa84fe2fbdc5b66f989aa86df98f
```

Answer (score 30):

The commands that helped me were:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

[Taken from here](https://www.herlitz.io/2020/12/01/docker-error-ports-are-not-available-on-windows-10/).

Answer (score 6):

> docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

I was also using [Docker's Getting Started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) tutorial, ran
`docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`, and got the same error.

I thought that Internet Information Services (IIS) might be using port 80 already. I verified this hunch by going to

Start > IIS > computer name > Sites > Default Web Site > highlight Default Web Site

[image: Left pane: computer name > Sites > Default Web Site > highlight Default Web Site, Right pane: Browse *.80 (http)]

In the right pane, I saw

Browse *.80 (http)

Yep, port 80 was already in use!

Note: To verify if *any* process is using port 80, run the command

`Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess`

and look for something like

```
 NPM(K)    PM(M)      WS(M)     CPU(s)      Id  SI ProcessName
 ------    -----      -----     ------      --  -- -----------
      0     0.20       2.96       0.00       4   0 System
```

per @Tim Dunphy's answer.

### Solution #1

Stop the Default Web site.

- Either go to IIS per above > right pane > Manage Website > Stop ***or***
- Use the `net stop http` command, and stop services using the port.

### Solution #2

You may not want to stop IIS or any other service running on port 80, so just change the local port! For example,

`docker run -d -p 81:80 docker/getting-started`

will likely do the trick, as long as you don't have services using port 81.

Answer (score 3):

When I encountered this error there was nothing actively listening on the port.However, the following command showed the port had been reserved by something else

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

See [This article](https://pomeroy.me/2020/09/solved-windows-10-forbidden-port-bind/) for more details. A reboot fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

in my case,the task manager show that a system process is occupy port 80.

when i dive deeper, i found a svchost.exe related to port 80, and it is based on **world wide web service**

so,**just open service list and stop the world wide web service,then everything will be ok**,the name of service maybe different, but should include keywords :world wide web

Answer (score 2):

Most times, Windows IIS (Internet Information Service) or some other program may be using port 80, which is the default http port used by Laravel, Apache and other PHP development environments.
To resolve this issue, Open a new PowerShell window as administrator and simply run this command:

```
net stop http
```

A prompt listing all services using the http port is shown and you are given the option of stopping them. enter 'Y' and press Enter. All the services are stopped and port 80 is now free for whatever you want to use it for.

Very useful for testing multiple application environments locally on Windows without having to worry about port configuration.

Comment: Thanks! In my case the http service was being used by: "Print Spooler" and "BranchCache". No idea what the latter is.

Answer (score 1):

just do it

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::
```

(This has to be run in a command prompt with elevated rights!)

Answer (score 1):

I had process blocking a port that I needed to use for a docker container and it took forever to resolve. In my case it was PID 4 using port 80 too.

Thought I'd summarise all of the potential issues and solutions I found while trying to resolve - hopefully useful for someone else in future.

---

For anyone new coming to this, you can investigate the service using the respective port by following these steps to try to figure out what it is.

In Powershell we can check for what process is using this port:

```
netstat -aon | findStr /i "LISTENING"  | findStr ":80"
```

To check what process this is:

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 4"
```

Another way to get the process ID using the port:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess
```

Check whether the port has ben reserved for use by another process with:

```
netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Also look in Resource Monitor to see if that gives you any more clues.

---

I tried all of the suggestions I found here and in other posts:

- [Disabling Hyper-V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234135/3567561) (`dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`)
- [Stopping HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68908192) (`net stop http`)
- [Restarting NAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65234135/3567561) (`net stop winnat; net start winnat`)
- [Restarting Host Network Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701504) (`restart-service hns`)

None of these worked to free up the port.

In the end I decided to check for any recent Windows Updates that could have caused it - there was nothing new in the last two weeks.

But when I check for recently installed applications (using Bulk Crap Uninstaller - it's excellent!) I noticed two 'apps' installed yesterday which I definitely didn't manually install so I think they somehow came through Win Update or an auto app update:

- Microsoft Edge Webview 2 Runtime
- Web Components

After uninstalling these, I had access to port 80 again!

To make sure it wouldn't happen again, I reserved the port for my own use:

```
netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=80 numberofports=1
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers to multiple questions.